# Is it possible to use variables in sdf file?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am in such a situation that I want to create the same type of robots in gazebo sharing one sdf file. The only differences are robots' name. So can I use a string array robot_name[index], for example, to replace the model name tags in sdf in my code using option 2 as this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world&cat=write_plugin) suggests. Or do you have any better solutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8305/is-it-possible-to-use-variables-in-sdf-file?/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-03-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the answer recently. I could use Ruby. Read these links:

1. [How can I declare a variable in model.sdf file?](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14063/how-can-i-declare-a-variable-in-modelsdf-file/);
2. [Algorithmic world generation](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8753/algorithmic-world-generation/)

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2016-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2